# rsync --sparse stalls every few seconds

Tags: rsync

```shellsession
$ rsync -aPhmS /mnt/data/ /mnt/data1/
```

I was copying some data around today and encountered a strange issue.

When using the `--sparse`, flag rsync performs much slower than expected:

`time rsync --sparse`

```
real    4m8.791s
user    0m23.558s
sys     2m43.257s
```

`time rsync` (no -s)

```
real    2m32.607s
user    0m39.175s
sys     1m33.885s
```

`time cp`

```
real    2m31.811s
user    0m0.254s
sys     0m52.627s
```

Monitoring the progress, every few seconds it stops writing and transfer speed drops to 0.
`iostat` reports device utilization of around 50-60% (which matches the timing above - the faster times are ~50-ish % of the slower).

Why does this happen?

Is there a fix or workaround for this performance problem? (Apart from no -S. The flag was there because some of the data includes sparse files.)

I can kind of imagine a piecemeal solution - detect all sparse files somehow, make a list of all non-sparse and all sparse files and run rsync twice off those lists. (But I'm very new to linux so such a script is way above me.)

rsync  version 3.2.7  protocol version 31

Answer (score 1):

The thing with the `--sparse` flag for `rsync`, is that it will need to analyze any file it wants to copy (not only sparse files) to see if it can create a sparse file in the destination.

Here's an example. I create a 1GB file which is **not** sparse.

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=bigfile bs=1G count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 0.65238 s, 1.6 GB/s
$ ls -lsh bigfile
1.0G -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.0G May 28 17:18 bigfile
```

Now notice that if I copy this file using `rsync --sparse`, the destination **will** be sparse, even though the source isn't.

```
$ time -p rsync --sparse bigfile bigfile.sparse
real 2.88
user 4.19
sys 0.56
$ ls -lsh bigfile.sparse
0 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.0G May 28 17:19 bigfile.sparse
```

This means that `rsync` needs to analyze this file to find out how it can be "sparsed". It needs to search for blocks of empty spaces that could be "sparsed" on the destination. That requires additional computation time.

By the way, it would do the same even for files that are already sparse. It will need to read the entire "extracted" source file, make the same analysis, and then create a new sparse file at the destination according to the analysis it did.

Comment: Interesting. That does make sense, tho I have some suspicions it may not be (entirely) what's happening here. But verifying this would require a lot more debugging than I'm capable of (or willing) to do. At least it means rsync has left a lot of optimizations on the table.